# Flask in combination with an event loop

Tags: python, api, flask, python-asyncio, iot

```
   import asyncio
   from automations import automation_trigger
   from scenes import call_scene
   from event_bus import state_loop



   try:
       loop.create_task(automation_trigger())              # Run Automations
       loop.create_task(state_loop())                      # Run event_bus
       loop.run_forever()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       pass
   finally:
       print("Closing Loop")
       loop.close()
```

Hello,

I want to make a smart home server for myself and the idea is that I have a server and an app that's communicate with an API.
The server does all the calculations and if something changes I can see it in the app.

The code that i white is an Asyncio event loop and when you run it then it checks if something is changed in the loop.
It works fine, but I want to add a Flask server in my project that makes an API page that I can connect to my app.

The problem is how can I add a Flask server to my project with an event loop run in the same time.
If I add the Flask server in my project at this moment it only runs the Flask server but not the event loop.

Is there a way to do it at the same time?

Comment: You probably want to use **ASGI**-compatible framework like https://pypi.org/project/Quart/ or use **gevent** or **eventlet** to somehow integrate **asyncio** or **aiotools**.

Answer (score 2):

You can start asyncio event loop on separate thread, while Flask runs on the main:

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread


def start_background_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

async def some_coro():
    return 1

def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    t = Thread(target=start_background_loop, args=(loop,), daemon=True)
    t.start()

    task = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(some_coro(), loop)
    res = task.result()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```